# Invalid calc() on IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, sass, internet-explorer-11, css-calc

Why IE11 can't calc this? I see from the console that it finds it invalid (in the compiled styles it's red underlined)

```
h6 {
  ...
  font-size: calc(calc((( (20 / 16) / 16 - 1 / 16) * (100vw - 20rem) / (992 / 16 - 20) + 1 / 16 * 1rem) * 16));
  ...
}
```

but instead this one is right:

```
body {
  ...
  font-size: calc((( (20 / 16) / 16 - 1 / 16) * (100vw - 20rem) / (992 / 16 - 20) + 1 / 16 * 1rem) * 16);
  ...
}
```

The calcs are compiled from scss, they're a result of multiple nested variable (each one containing a calc). If the problem is nesting `calc()`s how can I force Sass to remove the inside `calc()` functions?

It's like this:

```
  --f-min-font-size: 16;
  --f-max-font-size: 20;
  --f-text-gradient: (( (var(--f-max-font-size) / var(--f-min-font-size)) / 16 - var(--f-foot)) * var(--f-hill));
  --text-scale-ratio: 1.200;

  --body-font-size: calc(var(--f-text-gradient) * var(--f-min-font-size));

  --h6-font-size: calc(var(--body-font-size));
  --h5-font-size: calc(var(--h6-font-size) * var(--text-scale-ratio));
  --h4-font-size: calc(var(--h5-font-size) * var(--text-scale-ratio));
  --h3-font-size: calc(var(--h4-font-size) * var(--text-scale-ratio));
  --h2-font-size: calc(var(--h3-font-size) * var(--text-scale-ratio));
  --h1-font-size: calc(var(--h2-font-size) * var(--text-scale-ratio));
```

The CSS variables (custom properties) are compiled via Webpack [postcss-custom-properties](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-custom-properties) to normal CSS readable from IE (like the ones posted at beginning)

Some ideas?

Comment: This could potentially be considered a bug in that package… but it looks like you’ve shown the variables that produce the correct result (`font-size`). How is the `margin-bottom` defined?

Comment: Hi @Ry- that was just for sake of simplicity, I edited post for make it more clear. Don't know if it's a bug of postcss-custom-properties. If problem is nested calc()s, removing the inside ones looks like an optimization? I find this package but don't know https://github.com/postcss/postcss-calc

Comment: Could it be that the default unit for font-size is different on the body and h6 tag.

Comment: I try to check the browser support for [Calc()](https://caniuse.com/?search=calc) and found that it is partially supported in the IE browser. IE has some known issues with Calc(). It is possible that you meet with one of the known issues. Please check the known issues section in the mentioned link. I also found that SASS has some issues with the Calc(). I suggest you also check for it.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question but, I think it has to do with the nested calc function.https://codepen.io/zachhanding/post/nested-calc-functions-and-ie11

what you can do is either remove the calc inside the calc manually or use my postcss plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-remove-nested-calc